# determining Whether the power up is because of Reset Or power cut

Tags: embedded, stm32

how can I determine whether the power up is because power cut Or reset

I am working on STM32L152ZE

Regards,

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a [coding question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it is a coding question. I need to know why the processor is booting!!

Comment: I am tracking the time so if the boot was caused by reset that means the time is OK but if it was caused by power down  that means the time is corrupted

Comment: If it's a coding question, then please [show us the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I posted this question because I need a code or an advice at least

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages ["gimme teh codez"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288135/4200092) questions. You're more likely to get a response if you show us [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com/).

Comment: You already have an answer, but in the future, this kind of question is much more suited to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is your second question in as many days that is directly aswered by the user manual; let me help you with that: [STM32L100/151/152/162 User Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf)

Comment: Yeah, I hate to break it to you, but you're going to have a really bad time with microcontrollers if you can't learn read a datasheet.

Comment: actually I am new to this field. I came from High level language PC application (C#), that it best user manual is - guess what - .. GOOGLE . if you have a problem there, just google it. and you will get a very nice solutions because a lot of people already asked about it. Here it is different, I need to adapt with reading data sheets and user manuals. but it needs some time. So thank you for your help, and sorry for bothering

Answer (score 2):

1. Look up the datasheet for your processor.
2. Find the system status registers. There will be one that signifies the reason for boot up (for example, in a PIC, there is one that has bits indicating whether the boot was due to a watchdog timer, reset line, etc.)
3. Interrogate this register to find your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [STM32L100/151/152/162 User Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00240193.pdf) section section 6.3.14 describes the RCC_CSR register which has bit flags for all reset causes including Power On/Power Down Reset.